# Phalcon Model Relationship Select

Tags: php, phalcon

I have two models as such:

Inv (invoice)

InvItem (invoice line items)

When attempting to retrieve the InvItem through the Inv model, I get a 500 error. No error is reported on screen or in the log file. Reference https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#unidirectional-relationships

**Service Code**

```
$invoice = Inv::findFirst($id);
$item = $invoice->invItem;
```

**Inv Model Relationship**

```
Primary: inv_id
$this->hasMany('inv_id', 'InvItem', 'inv_id');
```

**InvItem Model Relationship**

```
Primary: inv_item_id
$this->belongsTo('inv_id', 'Inv', 'inv_id');
```

**Update (Added Models)**

*InvItem Model*

```
class InvItem extends InvBaseModel
{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $inv_item_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $inv_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $item;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $desc;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $quantity;

    /**
     *
     * @var double
     */
    public $rate;

    /**
     *
     * @var double
     */
    public $disc;

    /**
     * @var double
     */
    public $total;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('inv_id', 'Inv', 'inv_id');
    }
}
```

*Inv Model*

```
class Inv extends InvBaseModel
{
    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $inv_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $app_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $acct_contact_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $status;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $create_date;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $due_date;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $inv_date;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $sent_date;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $paid_date;


    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('inv_id', 'InvItem', 'inv_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: so `inv_id` is the primary key in the Inv model? and `inv_item_id` is the foreign key for InvItem model? To create a many to many relationship you need a third table (linking InvItem and Inv together).

Comment: Its a hasMany relationship: 1-n relationship. Two tables: Inv with inv_id and InvItem with inv_id, inc_item_id. Ivitem is a line item of Inv. (Think spreadsheet)

Comment: What is the primary key for InvItem and the foreign keys in InvItem

Comment: inv_item_id is the primary key for inv_item. The foreign key is inv_id which is present in both models.

Comment: Added model. See above

Comment: Well the relationship looks right then. What does `Inv::findFirst($id);` return?

Comment: It returns the proper inv model, however when $item = $invoice->invItem; is executed it returns a 500 error with nothing logged

Comment: replace `$this->hasMany('inv_id', 'InvItem', 'inv_id');` with `$this->hasMany('inv_id', 'InvItem', 'inv_id', array('alias' => 'inv_items'));` then you can use `$invoice->inv_items;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately this did not work. Same result. 500 Error. If I change the name to something that does not exist it outputs an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the namespace in the relationship model.

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany('inv_id', 'Multiple\Invoice\InvItem', 'inv_id');
}
```